# Vite how to prevent ,js filename change to other format

Tags: vite

I have config something like this

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: "src/main.ts",
            name: "main",
            fileName: "main",
            formats: ["cjs"],
        },
        outDir: ".",
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ["obsidian"],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    obsidian: "obsidian",
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

After build command it creates `main.cjs` file, I want it to be just `main.js`.
How can I achieve this.

Comment: did you try changing `cjs` to `js` in that config ?

Comment: I need `cjs` format specifically, in Rollup, there is way to left file extension untouched, I'm trying to figure out how to do the same in Vite

Answer (score 0):

In Vite, when you specify the fileName option as a string, Vite automatically adds the appropriate file extension. However, if you pass a function as the fileName option instead, you gain the ability to explicitly define the file extension yourself. This gives you greater control over the generated output file's name and extension.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/main.ts',
      name: 'main',
      fileName: () => 'main.js', // Use a function to specify the filename
      formats: ['cjs']
    },
    outDir: '.',
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['obsidian'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          obsidian: 'obsidian'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This is the signature for the function, in case you need more control:

```
((format: ModuleFormat, entryName: string) => string);
```